# Uncaught TypeError is raised for axios.create with axios version 0.22.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Uncaught TypeError is raised for axios.create with axios version 0.22.0

Exception is raised while creating axios instance with below sample code.

```
const service  = axios.create({
     baseURL: "host",
     timeout: 3000
})
```

Exception raised

```
axios.js:1308 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at mergeConfig (axios.js:1308)
    at Function.create (axios.js:1712)
    at request.js:32
```

Same works with axios version 0.21.4

Comment: This is an issue with axios, being followed up https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4153

Comment: Fix is avaiable with PR https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4140

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with axios https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4153.
Fix should be available from 0.23.0 onwards